# Парсинг JSON с помощью библиотеки Gson в Java

Tags: java, json, парсер, gson, десериализация

С недавнего времени решил познать работу с JSON, собственно при парсинге

```
{
"code": 10,
"fly": "ms-vl",
"text": [
    "Trans MS - VL"
]
}
```

все получается, но вот с кодом ниже не выходит

**Имеется JSON ответ:**

```
{
  "fly": [
     "ms-vl",
     "vl-rz",
     "rz-ms",
   ],
   "city": {
     "ms": "Москва",
     "vl": "Волгоград",
     "rz": "Рязань",

   }
}
```

**Пытаюсь парсить ответ с помощью Gson:**

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
GetCityInf inf = gson.fromJson(textss, GetCityInf.class);
System.out.println(inf);
```

**Класс `GetCityInf`:**

```
public class GetCityInf {

private GetFly fly;
private GetCity city;


public GetCityInf(){

}

public GetCityInf(GetFly fly, GetCity city){
    this.fly = fly;
    this.city = city;
}

  @Override
public String toString(){
   return "GetInform: fly - "+ fly + " city - " + city;
}

}
```

**Класс `GetFly`:**

```
public class GetFly {
String[] ArrayFly = null;


public GetFly(){

}

public GetFly(String[] fly){
    this.ArrayFly = fly;
}

public String GetFlyArray(){ return ArrayFly+"";}

}
```

**Класс `GetCity`:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GetCity {
HashMap<String, String> ArrayCity = null;


public GetCity(){

}

public GetCity(HashMap<String, String> array){
    this.ArrayCity = array;
}

public String GetCityArray() {
    return ArrayCity+"";
}


}
```

Comment: Что именно не получается? Какие ошибки? или просто распарсилось не туда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следующий класс больше подойдет для *десериализации* вашего JSON-значения:

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class GetCityInf {
  private List<String> fly;
  private Map<String, String> city;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Формат JSON ответа действительно был неверный, после исправления проблема снова повторялась. Ошибка была в неверно указанных типов  данных который должен был принимать класс.

Answer (score 2):

У вас JSON неверный, надо писать так:

```
{
  "fly": [
     "ms-vl",
     "vl-rz",
     "rz-ms"  //уберите запятую (в json комментарии запрещены, правда)
   ],
   "city": {
     "ms": "Москва",
     "vl": "Волгоград",
     "rz": "Рязань"  //уберите запятую (в json комментарии запрещены, правда)

   }
}
```

P.S. Для проверки корректности json используйте онлайн чекеры - [типа такого](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: А разве по новым стандартам в конце запятая не явлется допустмой?

Comment: Впервые слышу, но даже если это и так, то не уверен, что ТС применяет версию Gson, которая это понимает

Comment: Wiki(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSON5) говорит, что да. в JSON5 можно оставлять в конце запятую

Comment: Судя по списку открытых issue - Gson не поддерживает json5